# A friend wants to make a comment on one of my articles, she has to be logged to wordpress?

Tags: posts, comments

I have a friend, she does not have a blog or uses WordPress, she wants to drop a comment on one of my articles. Does she has to open a WordPress account? The blog demands a password to drop a comment?

Comment: The wording of this question makes me think that you are talking about a wordpress.com site. Is that correct? If so, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

In wp-admin, Settings » Discussion.

- **[Uncheck]** Users must be registered and logged in to comment

Your friend, as well as any anonymous user can post comment now without login.